# Rails Devise gem - customizing default User model by splitting it across other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, design-patterns, devise

I have tried the devise rails gem, and was wondering what the best way would be to split the user model attributes it creates across multiple models.

For now, my user model looks as follows, which is the default devise behaviour:

> User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string,
>   password_salt: string, reset_password_token: string, remember_token:
>   string, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer,
>   current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime,
>   current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at:
>   datetime, updated_at: datetime)

I would like to have some of the attributes below in another model, e.g. Watchdog

> sign_in_count, current_sign_in_at, last_sign_in_at,
>   current_sign_in_ip, last_sign_in_ip

I was considering of simple delegating them using the delegate method:

```
delegate :sign_in_count, :sign_in_count=, ..., :to => :watchdog
```

Would be interested in hearing about better solutions to this problem.

Thanks,

Sergio

Answer (score 2):

You can also create your own concern that does the same without having to override Devise internals. After doing that, only extend `Trackable module` on your model.

```
    module Trackable
      def update_tracked_fields!(request)
        old_current, new_current = watchdog.current_sign_in_at, Time.now.utc
        watchdog.last_sign_in_at     = old_current || new_current
        watchdog.current_sign_in_at  = new_current

        old_current, new_current = self.current_sign_in_ip, request.ip
        watchdog.last_sign_in_ip     = old_current || new_current
        watchdog.current_sign_in_ip  = new_current

        watchdog.sign_in_count ||= 0
        watchdog.sign_in_count += 1

        watchdog.save(:validate => false)
      end
    end
```

But don't forget to put `record.update_tracked_fields!(warden.request)` on the `Warden::Manager.after_set_user` block as we do on [Devise hook](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/trackable.rb).