# Splitting devise users table into two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a users table integrated with devise gem. The table has certain fields like current_sign_in_ip, last_sign_in_ip,current_sign_in_at, etc. Devise modifies these fields when the user logs in. 
I would like these fields to be moved to another table and populate them via devise or otherwise. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: `devise :trackable` to that model where you have to transfer the fields

Answer (score 5):

There are two approaches to this answer:

The first (and easier, although not as pretty) option is to delegate the `:trackable` methods to a second class (called UserDetail below). For example:

```
class UserDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :current_sign_in_ip, :last_sign_in_ip .... to: :user_detail

  ...
end
```

A cleaner option would be create a concern that avoids overriding Devise. You'd have to extend this on to your `User` model:

```
module Trackable
  def update_tracked_fields!(request)
    old_current, new_current = user_detail.current_sign_in_at, Time.now.utc
    user_detail.last_sign_in_at     = old_current || new_current
    user_detail.current_sign_in_at  = new_current

    old_current, new_current = self.current_sign_in_ip, request.ip
    user_detail.last_sign_in_ip     = old_current || new_current
    user_detail.current_sign_in_ip  = new_current

    user_detail.sign_in_count ||= 0
    user_detail.sign_in_count += 1

    user_detail.save(:validate => false)
  end
end
```

I got the second solution from Rodrigo Flores via [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466990/rails-devise-gem-customizing-default-user-model-by-splitting-it-across-other-m) He reminds us to put `record.update_tracked_fields!(warden.request)` on the `Warden::Manager.after_set_user` block like they do [here.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/trackable.rb)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It helped me, for sure. Though, I would like to mention how I finally went about it. I did not use delegate, because I wanted one-to-many relationship between my User model and the UserLogs model, and i wanted the user_logs table to be an insert-only table. So, I overrided the devise update_tracked_fields according to it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response. It helped me to move in the correct direction.
Let me share how I went about solving the problem I was facing.

As I wanted one-to-many relationship between users and user_logs table, I could not delegate the trackable methods to the UserLog model.
Also, I wanted the user_logs table to be an insert-only table, hence I needed to override update_tracked_fields method of Devise Trackable module accordingly.

So :

1. I created a new user_logs table and UserLog model.
2. Overrid the update_tracked_fields method to actually insert a new row everytime in the user_logs table instead of updating users table.
3. Created getter methods for these trackable fields in User model that actually fetches required column value from the user_logs table. Like this :

   ```
   self.try(:user_logs).last.try(:current_sign_in_ip)
   ```